How can I calculate a transistor's IB, VBB and VEE from the given information?
I'm new to using transistors, and struggling with a problem that resembles this:

As you can see, we have a few known variables:

VCC is 5V
IE is 20mA

There are also some variables with a range:

IB is under or equal to 5mA
IC is therefore greater or equal to 15mA

Is there a way to calculate the other variables I need from this information? If so, how?
Also, if more information is needed, what other variables do I need to know?
PS: I'm looking for a way to precisely calculate, as opposed to approximations.

Where did you get your numbers?  β is typically 100 to 300 for a 2N3904 and yours is 3.  Given existing info, you cannot calculate much.

Without considering every one of the transistor's parameters and quirks and variations across devices, there's no such thing as a precise calculation, everything is an approximation. If you define what you consider to be an approximation, maybe you'll get a good answer.

Steam, unless you have already selected a very specific NPN model (and all associated models that relate to it, such as the saturation current model over temperature and device physics) and know all of the device parameters for that model, and know the die temperature, there's no way you can calculate the precise model-derived values. So back off a bit. What are you really on about here?

R will be equal to V=IR, you know the current through R and you can approximate the voltage to be something like 0.7V across the transistor, so you can know something about the voltage across R.

Assuming this is related to your previous question about driving LEDs from a shift-register, it's not going to be particularly easy to calculate the numbers exactly because there are a bunch of things you don't specify and may not know.
At reasonable currents such as 5-15 mA the emitter voltage will be about 0.7V lower than the base voltage. That is pretty accurate in relation to the supply voltage of 5V you mentioned.
The current will be determined by the LED forward voltage curve (note that it's not constant with current), the resistor value and the cathode driver voltage drop.
There's another twist, the base will draw some current from the shift register which will mean the base voltage will be less than 5V by a bit. Generally that current will be less than 1/100 of the emitter current.
The Vf of the LEDs and the resistor value you pick (together with the supply voltage) will be the biggest factors.
Generally to do your design you will add up the voltage drop of the transistor and the cathode driver and the LED and calculate the series resistor to get close to the desired value. The resistor can be calculated from Ohm's law- the supply voltage minus the sum of the three aforementioned voltage drops is the voltage across the resistor. So if the voltage is 1.5V and you wanted 10mA (2.5mA average) you could use 150Ω. You should operate the LEDs well below maximum current to allow for tolerances and for long life.
If you were doing a commercial design you'd also evaluate the sensitivity of the LED current to changes and differences in the components to make sure it would operate acceptably and reliably no matter what batch the parts were and what the operating conditions are.

I hadn't considered putting the entire circuit as one equation, I was going to calculate the anode and cathode transistor seperately, but yeah it is better. This answer in conjunction with Neil_UK's haven't solved my problem, but let me realise it isn't actually a problem.

You're not given the base or emitter voltage. So knowing the emitter current doesn't tell you the value of R1. All you know is that the emitter voltage is somewhere between 2 V and 5 V (making some reasonable assumptions), so R1 is somewhere between 0 Ω and 150 Ω.
A base voltage, or a base current and transistor beta, would be needed to improve on that range, to give you the emitter voltage. Unless of course the exercise is to come up with some values, and complete the calculations around those. In which case, choose 1 V or 2 V for the voltage across R1, which are reasonable values so that this voltage swamps variations in VBE with temperature and Ib.
Precision is never warranted with this type of circuit or bias calculation. You can expect transistor beta to vary by a factor of 3 from device to device, and VBE varies with device temperature. We often use 100 for beta when doing quick bias calculations. It's not untypical for signal transistors, makes the sums easy, and is close enough to infinity for most purposes. If you need precision, then you use feedback to stabilise bias conditions.
One place precision might be asked for is in an academic setting, your tutor might want to see whether you can do all the sums. Far better would be to do limiting sums, bounds at min and max temperature, and min and max beta, to see whether the topology of the chosen bias circuit can cope with the range of conditions that will be thrown at it.

I hadn't actually considered the variation of the transistor. I think the precision I was hoping for isn't quite warranted.

Use Kirchoffs voltage law, Kirchoff's current law and rues of a NPN BJT such as \$I_c = I_b * h_{fe}\$ and \$I_b\$ = \$\frac{I_e}{hfe + 1}\$. β of the BJT is also called \$h_{fe}\$. Given a range of \$I_b\$ and DC value of \$I_e\$ , you can estimate a range of \$h_fe\$ that it is greater than some value. After calculating \$h_{fe}\$, you can calculate \$I_c\$.

The problem is that β on the datasheet is a curve that coincides with collector current, which is perfectly reasonable. However, I want to calculate the base current, which affects the collector current, which affects β, which is used in calculating base current, so I've got a circular dependency.

The problem shows instantaneous values of DC currents in emitter and base. Therefore, estimation of β according to these currents and voltages at collector and emitter and base is fine. It also seems vague regarding base current. Some other parameter might have been necessary.
